# Using "lower" and "upper" aggregate functions on JOOQ Postgres range types

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I'm using the Postgres `numrange` type with JOOQ as [defined here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.17/manual-single-page/#codegen-extension-postgres) and want to call the `lower`/`upper` aggregate function on the selected ranges. My understanding is that these functions are not actually implemented in the `jooq-postgres-extensions` module and that I somehow have to implement this myself. Reading through [this blog post](https://blog.jooq.org/postgresqls-best-kept-secret-and-how-to-use-it-with-jooq/), the author mentions that these functions have to be implemented yourself and he gives some examples:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> Condition 
    rangeContainsElem(Field<Range<T>> f1, T e) {
    return DSL.condition("range_contains_elem({0}, {1})", f1, val(e));
}
 
static <T extends Comparable<T>> Condition 
    rangeOverlaps(Field<Range<T>> f1, Range<T> f2) {
    return DSL.condition("range_overlaps({0}, {1})", f1, val(f2, f1.getDataType()));
}
```

However, he does not show any implementation of the `lower`/`upper` functions. How are these functions implemented?

Ideally, the end-goal would be to be able to do something like this, where the lower and upper bound of a column of ranges is retrieved:

```
val rangeMetadata = create.select(
         BigDecimalRange(
             max(upper(RANGE_PARAMETER.VALUE)),
             true,
             min(lower(RANGE_PARAMETER.VALUE)),
             true
         )
     )
     .from(RANGE_PARAMETER)
     .fetch()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a big difference between defining your `rangeOverlaps()` and a `lower()` or `upper()` aggregate function, you can do it exactly the same way. In order to map that data directly into the `BigDecimalRange` type, you can use:

- [Nested records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/nested-records/)
- [Ad hoc conversion](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/)

```kotlin
create.select(
          row(
              max(upper(RANGE_PARAMETER.VALUE)),
              min(lower(RANGE_PARAMETER.VALUE))
          ).mapping { u, l -> bigDecimalRange(u, true, l, true) }
      )
      .from(RANGE_PARAMETER)
      .fetch()
```

A note regarding:

> My understanding is that these functions are not actually implemented in the jooq-postgres-extensions module and that I somehow have to implement this myself

There isn't a big reason why this shouldn't be done. It's just a task that hasn't been implemented *yet*. I've created an issue for this. Could be useful to support this out of the box: [#13828](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13828)

#### How to create a plain SQL templating `Field<T>`

Apparently, there seems to be a difficulty to going from the plain SQL templating `Condition` (which you already have) to a `Field<T>`, but it's just the same thing:

```java
public static Field<BigDecimal> upper(Field<? extends BigDecimalRange> f) {
    return DSL.field("upper({0})", SQLDataType.NUMERIC, f);
}
```

See also:

- [Plain SQL](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/)
- [Plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)

Comment: Thanks for your response Lukas. Despite the hints you give here it's not immediately obvious to me, as someone who's not familiar with the inner workings of JOOQ, what this function should look like. More specifically, what is the input and return type supposed to be? Here is my best attempt so far:
`static <T extends Record> Condition lower(TableField<T, BigDecimalRange> f1) {
    return DSL.condition("lower({0})", f1);
}`

Comment: @Joachim: No need to learn about the *inner* workings of jOOQ. Your `DSL::condition` call isn't applicable here, just use `DSL::field`. I've updated the answer with an example

Comment: By inner workings, I guess I meant understanding fundamental concepts like the difference between conditions and fields ;) I got this to work now with your help. Thank you very much!